# How to plot $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{W(-e^{-y^2/2-1})+1}=x$ in Matlab?

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I  would like to plot in Matlab the following implicit equation:
 $$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{W(-e^{-y^2/2-1})+1}=x,$$
where $W(\cdot)$ is the Lambert $W$ function.
I am trying to plot it symbolically with `ezplot` but Matlab's `lambertw` function does not allow symbolic inputs. How would you plot it?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know MATLAB doesn't provide any facilities for plotting functions given with implicit equations. The closest I thing can think of is [`fplot`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html), but it requires a vector function of the form $y = f(x)$. You'll likely need to solve the equation, first.

Comment: With `ezplot` you can plot implicit equations. The problem is how to deal with the integral. I do not mind to solve the equation but I do not know how.

Comment: Maybe you can take inspiration from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21062/how-to-solve-a-non-linear-integral-equation) on the Mathematica SE. The answer uses Mathematica, but you may be able to write equivalent MATLAB code.

Comment: What do mean by "Matlab's `lambertw` function does not allow symbolic inputs"? `lambertw` is entirely symbolic.

Comment: Does the integral need to be indefinite? Can you provide integration bounds?